# c# Razor - how best to manage Markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Just starting out with c# Razor, (but experienced in other tech I'm used to nodejs/php/ruby etc) quick question regarding proper syntax

```
 @{
    var test = "";
    if (Model.ItemNo != null)
    {
        test = "<div>";
        test += "<div style='padding:3px'>";
        test += "<label>ItemNo</label>";
        test += Model.ItemNo;
        test += "</div>";
        test += "</div>";
    }
}
```

should I do it better like this?

```
@{
    var test = "";
    if (Model.ItemNo != null)
    {
        test = @<div>
           <div style='padding:3px'>
            <label>ItemNo</label>
               @Model.ItemNo;
             </div> 
           </div> 
    }
}
```

but it doesn't like it, am I missing something?

*I need to pre-prepare the string like this because it goes into a Kendo Tab as an optional .Content(); string*

this works

```
   @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabstrip")
        .Items(tabItem =>
        {
            tabItem.Add()
                .Text("Optional Data")
                .Selected(true)
                .Content(@<div>
           <div style='padding:3px'>
            <label>ItemNo</label>
               @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ItemNo)
               @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemNo)
             </div> 
           </div>);
        }
   }
```

this works

```
   @{
     var test = "";
     if (Model.ItemNo != null)
     {
        test = "<div>";
        test += "<div style='padding:3px'>";
        test += "<label>ItemNo</label>";
        test += Model.ItemNo;
        test += "</div>";
        test += "</div>";
     }
   }

   @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabstrip")
        .Items(tabItem =>
        {
            tabItem.Add()
                .Text("Optional Data")
                .Selected(true)
                .Content(test);
        }
   }
```

but the @div in JavaScript doesn't

Kendo doesn't let you optionally add these with a if statement in the kendo  -> .Add().Content() content, but it does accept a javascript variable

Comment: Why on earth are you writing html like that?  Just write HTML in the actual body and put the `@Model.ItemNo` inside it

Comment: I did a quick mockup on DotNetFiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cmdE2P).  This is the proper way of using razor.  DotNetFiddle is having some issues this morning it seems so if it does not load at first just try again.

Comment: because it's a java-script variable

Comment: @MrHeelis The code you have included in your question does not show a javascript variable in any way.  Also that does not matter because you can literally just use Javascript in the body as usual but not concatenating strings in C#

Comment: Maybe post how kendo tabs looks like? Not everyone knows how it works.

Comment: Pretty sure that does not accept JavaScript variable... That's a Kendo's HTML Helper. You can still do conditional if statement inside `.Content()`. Razor View Engine != JavaScript

Comment: yes, 12seconds, I know what i am doing, the razor "helpful" platform and the kendo "helper" are too dumbed down, it's sheer obfuscation making it exponentially hard to optionally expose markup to a container.. it's incredibly pathetically easy to do this normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on KendoUI [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/tabstrip/overview#use-forms-inside-tabstrips) you can provide `@<text></text>` to `.Content()`.

You should be doing something similar to this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(tabItem =>
    {
        tabItem.Add()
            .Text("Optional Data")
            .Selected(true)
            .Content(@<text>

                 <div>
                   <div style='padding:3px'>
                     <label>ItemNo</label>
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ItemNo)
                     @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemNo)
                   </div> 
                 </div>

            </text>);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , but technically you re-iterated what I know works in my OP- I need to optionally add if/else div markup in the content

Comment: @MrHeelis I don't have Kendo UI to test it out, but you should be able to still do something like `@if (condition) { }` inside of `@<text></text>` Give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

You should write HTML directly in the HTML, like this:

```
<html>
    @if (Model.ItemNo != null)
    {
        <div>
            <div style='padding:3px'>
                <label>ProdOrderNo</label>
                @Model.ItemNo
            </div> 
        </div> 
    }
</html>
```

Comment: You dont need the `;`

Comment: @maccettura, I fixed it

Comment: this doesn't work to embedding markup, or run time rending, it only works on server side

Comment: @MrHeelis its very unclear what you are saying.  Razor code _only_ works on the server.

Comment: that's not quite true, it accepts raw markup at server side but it renders it itself using javascript, if it *weren't* true it wouldn't render the `var test ` as markup, (and it does)

but even if it did accept raw markup it doesn't allow me to optionally replace which raw markup

Comment: @MrHeelis, Razor view is not render by JavaScript, it is not Javascript framework/library like Angular, React, or VueJS. Razor is compiled on the server side and returns HTML

Comment: @MrHeelis I did not notice your comment until now.  You are very, _very_ wrong about Razor.  Razor absolutely, 100% is ran server side.  The browser downloads the "rendered" HTML that the Razor code produces.  Your comments are very hard to understand but the best I can tell is that you are very misinformed about the `var` keyword as it pertains to C#.  The `var` in C# is not the same as a `var` in javascript.  Its just syntactic sugar in C#.  The compiler knows what type it is, its not a generic "type".